# Is jquery interface.js com always working with the new version of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the interface.js website (http://interface.eyecon.ro/) they propose to download `interface.js` with jQuery 1.1.2. I would like to know if interface.js is still compliant with the new version of jQuery and if there will be a new release of this library.

I had some trouble to use jQuery 1.2.x with interface 1.2, and using jQuery 1.1.4 correct bugs I had.

Sorry for my bad English, hope someone understands my question ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the interface library. It is now unsupported and superseeded by [jquery-ui](http://ui.jquery.com/) and you will have major issues working with the latest jQuery 1.3 I suspect.

See [this following post](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-ui/browse_thread/thread/9436f24519e35369/1f06c0bdd28155e8) and reply by Scott one of the jquery-ui developers

Answer (score 0):

The interface library is there more as an archive now. The newest version of jquery (1.3) will not work with it.

All the interface stuff is now an official part of the jquery site and is well documented. You can download it from http://ui.jquery.com/